# Save image from mjpeg stream

Tags: java, stream, jpeg, mjpeg

I’m trying to capture image(jpeg) from MJPEG stream. 
According to this tutorial http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2010/04/20/motion-jpeg-in-flash-and-java/
I should just save date starting from Content-Length: and ending at –myboundary. 
But for some reason when I open a saved file I get this message Can’t open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted or is too large.

```
public class MJPEGParser{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MJPEGParser("http://192.168.0.100/video4.mjpg");
    }

    public MJPEGParser(String mjpeg_url){
        try{

            URL url = new URL(mjpeg_url);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                if(line.contains("Content-Length:")){
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.jpeg"));
                    String content = in.readLine();
                    while(!content.contains("--myboundary")){
                        out.write(content);
                        System.out.println(content);
                        content = in.readLine();

                    }
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }

            in.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

I will be really grateful for any tips.

Comment: Try using an OutputStreamWriter http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html instead of BufferedWriter

Comment: Don't use `Reader` and `Writer` at all! Your data is made up from bytes, not characters, so use byte streams instead. To identify this header thingy, either look for the matching bytes or convert the bytes of the herader only to Strings using a suitable character set.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things which might cause your code to fail for you:

- Not all [MJPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) streams are encoded in the MIME-like fashion your tutorial suggests.
  Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#Disadvantages):

  > […] there is no document that defines a single exact format that is universally recognized as a complete specification of “Motion JPEG” for use in all contexts.

  For example, one may use MJPEG as the video codec of an [AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) (i.e. [RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format)) file. So make sure your input file is in the format the tutorial describes.
- The text `--myboundary` is almost certainly a placeholder. In a typical [multipart MIME message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages), the global MIME header will provide a `boundary` attribute, indicating what string is *actually* used to delimit parts. You'll have to prepend `--` to the string given there.
- As you are using `Reader` and `Writer`, you are operating on characters, not bytes. Depending on your locale, there might not be a 1:1 correspondence between these two, thus breaking the binary format of the data in the process. You should either operate on byte streams, or explicitely use some character encoding like ISO-8859-1 which *does* have such a 1:1 correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this issue recently, and my google research brought me here multiple times. I eventually solved the problem. The key part is using `BufferedInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to read and write jpeg bytes, while also concatenating byte buffers into a string to read and identify headers between frames:

```java
int inputLine;
String s="";
byte[] buf = new byte[1]; //reading byte by byte 

URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/?action=stream");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.jpg");
        
while ((inputLine = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
 
    s= s+ new String(buf, 0, inputLine);

    if (s.contains("boundarydonotcross")){
        System.out.println("Found a new header");
        s="";
    }
```

The complete code is here if anybody needs it:

https://github.com/BabelCoding/MJPEG-to-JPG